# Change wordpress sql database for custom post types

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to change default database for custom posts types from wp_posts to wp_anything_else, I need to have unique ID that is taken only by certain posts. For example if I have post type blog it will add it as well to wp_posts and I don't want that, it messes everything up :(
Is there way to change database when making custom post type in functions.php or with any plugin?

*code from functions.php

```html
add_filter('body_class','bp_conditional_ie_classes');
/*custom post types*/
add_action('init', 'blogs_register');
 
function blogs_register() {
 
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('My Blog', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Blog Item', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Blog item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Blog Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Blog Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New Blog Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View Blog Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Blog'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
 
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
      ); 
 
    register_post_type( 'blogs' , $args );
}
```

**snippet don't work, but that was only way it allows me to add code without messing it

Comment: Can you clarify "messes everything up"?

Comment: In order for other things to work i need to keep all post ID in sequence ( posts to be in ID's from 50 till 150, and just posts)

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong elsewhere in your application. I would focus on why you need separate tables and correct that issue.

Comment: I can't change that part, other app pick random post by id and send mail to certain people

Comment: How does this other app avoid picking revisions, attachments or pages? `post` is not the only type stored in `wp_posts` even without creating custom types. To address your question, there is no easy way to separate post types into different tables and even if there were you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress posts (posts, pages, custom posts, ...) are meant to represent one single entity of your website. Because of that abstraction WordPress uses one single table for all of its content types, so during an average site request WP has to lookup the requested site in only one table.

Having multiple post types in multiple tables would require a different lookup behaviour in WP's kernel. That's why what you want is complicated to do.

Even though i'm sure that a separate DB table is not needed for "blog items", the problem I see with the `wp_posts` table is that they do not enable `m:n`-relations between its entries. For such a use case you could think about using a combination of custom posts and custom taxonomies.

Edit: Of course you can write or use (if there exists one) a plugin which handles all the stuff needed to manage and maintain an additional table. But that will probably never integrate into WordPress as well as custom post types.